# Entity method - setPropertiesFrom

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to clone an Entity.

Question on Entity method

Entity.setPropertiesFrom(Entity src).

The documentation says
"A convenience method that populates the properties of this Entity with the properties set on the provided Entity. This method transfers information about unindexed properties"

How about indexed properties?  Do they get populated as well.

-Aswath

Comment: Have you tried it in your code to see if it transfers indexed properties as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it transfers all properties.  I suspect that the docs mean that if a property is unindexed in the source entity, it will also be marked as unindexed in the target... but I don't know for sure.